# scroll display pagination with knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, infinite-scroll

I would like to use knockout js to enable scroll pagination

**Problem**
I would like to pass in `url` and `id` into my `GetPage(controller, id#, page#))
Currently it is hard coded but i would like to change that.

**Knockout js**

```
   $.views.Roster.GetPage = function (url, id, pageNumber) {
        $.grain.Ajax.Get({
            Url: url,
            SectionID: {id:id},
            DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: pageNumber, id: id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);

            }
        });
    };

Next = function () {
        var _page = $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage() + 1;
        $.views.Roster.ViewModel.CurrentPage(_page);
        $.views.Roster.GetPage("/api/Roster", 9, _page);
    }
```

**Scroll pagination**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').scroll(function () {

        if ($('#main').scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $('#main').height()) {
            $('#status').text('Loading more items...' + $.views.Roster.ViewModel.TotalRoster());
            if ($.views.Roster.ViewModel.RosterUsers() == null ) {
                $('#status').hide();
                $('#done').text('No more items...'),
                $('#main').unbind('scroll');
            }
            setTimeout(updateStatus, 2500);
        }
        //updateStatus();
    });
});
```

Comment: where is your ajax call? put that up too please. The entire viewmodel will be awesome!

Comment: @sujeshArukil I updated my post - it will be amazingly awesome if you can help me out again on this.

Comment: so are you returning all users at once or still sending 20 users at a time from the server?

Comment: @sujeshArukil i would like to pull 20 users to show on a page but as the user goes to the next page another 20 are displayed and will continue until all the users on the server are shown (which are about 250 in my case) so i should have about 13 pages of users each showing 20 users at a time

Comment: then you have to change the way you are making the ajax call. this comment box is too short for this, let me modify your code and give it to you

Comment: where are you calling applyBindings?

Comment: @sujesharukil i am not using applyBindings but i added the script sections that i have on the view page that calls the the knockout js and renders the info. Thank you soo much i will be looking forward to your code suggestion.

Comment: and where is this function defined? "_makeRequest"

Comment: @sujeshArukil sorry i meant to take that out because i wasn't using that feature. I am only using the next and prev buttons to see if pagination by button click works.

Comment: no keep it. That is what will help you with this. give me 10 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the data in getRoster function to what your server function is expecting for you to return the data. Also, remove the code $.views.Roster.GetRoster, it is not required anymore. Now when you do ko.applyBindings(new $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel()); you should get the first page of data, subsequently, when you scroll, the next() call on the view model will continue paging. That logic is all you.

```
$.views.Roster.RosterViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.RosterUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    _rosterUsers = self.RosterUsers;
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
    self.toDisplay = ko.observable(10);

    var filteredRoster = ko.computed(function(){
        var init = (self.currentPage()-1)* self.toDisplay(),
            filteredList = [],
            rosterLength = self.RosterUsers().length,
            displayLimit = self.toDisplay();
        if(rosterLength == 0)
            return[];
        for(var i = init; i<(displayLimit + init)  && i<rosterLength; i++)
        {
            filteredList.push(self.RosterUsers()[i]);
        }
        return filteredList;
    }),
    totalRoster = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.RosterUsers().length;
    }),
    changePage = function (data) {
        self.currentPage(data);
    },
    next = function () {
        if ((self.currentPage() * self.toDisplay()) > self.RosterUsers().length)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() + 1);
    },
    prev = function () {
        if (self.currentPage() === 1)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() - 1);
    },
    getRoster = ko.computed(function () {
        var data = {
            currentPage: self.currentPage(),
            pageSize: self.toDisplay()
        },
            $promise = _makeRequest(data);

        $promise.done(function (data) {
            var localArray = [];
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(d){
                localArray.push(new $.views.Roster.UserViewModel(d));
            });
            self.RosterUsers.push.apply(self.RosterUsers,localArray);
        });

    }),
        _makeRequest = function(data){
            return $.getJSON('your url here', data);
        };



};
```

Comment: Thanks - i am working through implementing this but i got an `uncaught type error: undefined is not a function` for this line of code in knockout `$promise = _makeRequest(data);`

Comment: put the _makeRequest above the getRoster function. that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes it did work but i had to do other changes and know i am able to get all 200+ users - showing 20 on a page and getting the next 20 by clicking next. I am still having trouble getting the scroll working in place of the click next button. - I have a small question in which i will update my code if you can take a look - i want to pass in a parameter rather than hard coding it.

Comment: Hey again - i was wondering if you would be able to help me out by showing me how can i know that i've reached the end of list of data to display so i can notify the user that there is no more data?

Comment: You are bringing down 20 at a time. So if the data that comes back is less than 20 you know that there is no more data. That is one way, but it will come at the cost of that one occasional extra call to the server when you get the last 20 in the list. Another way is to send the total and keep a count of ajax calls you make. So that count multiplies by 20 should always be less than the total number of records.

Comment: I think i will go with the first suggestion at least it is something i believe i could do. Also i updated my scroll code because currently the page loads the first 20 users when i scroll to the bottom of the page it loads the next 200 users. sorry but u have been the only one able to help me.

Comment: it is difficult to tell what is going on without actually looking at the calls being made. If I may suggest, you should look at debugging tools. Chrome Dev tools is great for these things. Learn a lot about making ajax calls and knockout in general. Here is an excellent resource on how to work with chrome dev tools http://addyosmani.com/blog/tag/chrome-developer-tools/. From my initial thoughts, there is some calculation mistake on the number of records you are requesting from the server. So breakpoints, debug and I am sure you will figure it all out.